# how to make view from query contain sub query

Tags: mysql

i want to make view with this query, but it cannot make a view because it's contain sub query, anyone can help me ? please.. and thanks

```
FROM
(  
    SELECT * ,
    @row_num :=IF(@prev_value = concat_ws('',Nama),@row_num+1,1)AS RowNumber
    , @prev_value := concat_ws('',Nama) AS Temp
    FROM trackku A,
    (SELECT @row_num := 0) r
    ORDER BY Nama,tgl_angsur
)T1
LEFT JOIN
(  
    SELECT * ,
    @row_num2 :=IF(@prev_value2 = concat_ws('',Nama),@row_num2+1,1)AS RowNumber2
    , @prev_value2 := concat_ws('',Nama) AS Temp
    FROM trackku B,
    (SELECT @row_num2 := 0) r
    ORDER BY Nama,tgl_angsur
)T2 ON T1.Nama = T2.Nama
AND T1.RowNumber = T2.RowNumber2 + 1;
```

please help me

Comment: MySQL permits views to use neither variables not subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  Please edit your question and provide sample data, desired resuls, and an explanation of what the code should be doing.  You should also note if you are using MySQL 8+.

Comment: *"MySQL permits views to use neither variables not subqueries in the FROM clause"* @GordonLinoff the subqueries in FROM clause are not the problem, MySQL supports using deliverd tables just fine in VIEWS

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . Cool.  It didn't used to (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6aa32eac0006f533928c186e6a7ec9cc).  I guess I missed that that changed.

Comment: Post the actual error you are receiving.

Comment: *" I guess I missed that that changed. "* @GordonLinoff well from MySQL 5.7 and up it works fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6aa32eac0006f533928c186e6a7ec9cc